# Excel - how to generate a list of unique

Tags: excel

need to create a list in excel for all possible combinations (unique): Let say there are 5 buttons (e.g A B C D E) and 3 are selected. For any single combination, any selected button can't be repeated in that combination.

I should get 60 unique combinations ( 5 1 ) * ( 4 1 ) * ( 3 1 ) = 60. I need to create this list in excel.

e.g have A B C D E buttons. 3 buttons combinations: A B C; C B A; D A C; C D A; A D C; etc.

Comment: i know how to create all possible permutations using vba code (just found) from the source list (e.g. A B C D E).. but i still want to know how to create permutations when only 3 unique buttons out of 5 are selected in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

By *"unique"* I assume that you want to exclude things like *AAD* or *ABB*.

Consider:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Kombos()
    Dim arr(1 To 5) As String
    Dim brr(1 To 5) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim N As Long, V As String
    arr(1) = "A"
    arr(2) = "B"
    arr(3) = "C"
    arr(4) = "D"
    arr(5) = "E"
    N = 1
    
    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = i + 1 To 4
            For k = j + 1 To 5
                Cells(1, N) = arr(i) & arr(j) & arr(k)
                N = N + 1
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    For i = 1 To 10
        V = Cells(1, i).Value
        brr(1) = Left(V, 1)
        brr(2) = Mid(V, 2, 1)
        brr(3) = Right(V, 1)
        Cells(2, i) = brr(1) & brr(3) & brr(2)
        Cells(3, i) = brr(2) & brr(1) & brr(3)
        Cells(4, i) = brr(2) & brr(3) & brr(1)
        Cells(5, i) = brr(3) & brr(1) & brr(2)
        Cells(6, i) = brr(3) & brr(2) & brr(1)
    Next i
        
End Sub
```

[image]

Each column is a different combination of 5 elements taken 3 at a time. *(10 columns)*

The rows below the first row list the various permutations of the column header.